# how to use legacySQL to query table with partition column

Tags: google-bigquery

Currently I am getting a 
`Querying tables partitioned on a field is not supported in Legacy SQL`
What can I do to use Legacy Sql to query a partitioned table?

Comment: that is if the partition column is named something else and not _PARTITIONTIME or _PARTITIONDATE

Comment: (I'm using legacy SQL, because this is what our version of composer airflow is on now. airflow 1.9-composer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do to use Legacy Sql to query a partitioned table?

You can't use legacy SQL to query a partitioned table, as the error message says.

> I'm using legacy SQL, because this is what our version of composer airflow is on now. airflow 1.9-composer

In most tools that don't provide an explicit option for the query dialect, you can use the `#standardSQL` shebang, e.g.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dataset.partitioned_table
```

Answer (score 0):

In the apps script editor you have to state LegacySql to `false`, for example:

```
var projectId = 'xxxxxxx';
    
var request = {
  query: 'select * from project.database.table',
  useLegacySql: false
};
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
```